# Python numpy - DepricationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am quite new to data science/python, and currently I am working on some deep learning algorithms where I would like to use one variable for both input and output data. I have 4 inputs and 1 output. I use the following structure:

```
 samples = np.zeros(nb_samples, dtype=[('input', float, 4), ('output', float, 1)] )
```

and get the following warning, when I StandardScale, the array:

```
 DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise 
 ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your
  data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I think the problem is that my structure looks like this:

```
 [ [x0,x1,x2,x3], y0 ]
```

And it should look something like this:

```
 [ [x0,x1,x2,x3], [y0] ]
```

I found some similar questions but none of the answers worked for me.

How can I solve this warning? And what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using 0.19.1 and indeed I get an error when I try to scale this array. But here's the transformation that works for me:

```py
samples = np.zeros(nb_samples, dtype=[('input', float, 4), ('output', float, 1)])
x = samples['input']     # shape=(nb_samples, 4)
y = samples['output']    # shape=(nb_samples,)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(x, y)  # does the same with and without `y`
```

Separation of `input` and `output` is better particularly for `StandardScaler`, because it scales only `x` and doesn't do anything to `y`. [In fact](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), the `y` is a "passthrough argument for `Pipeline` compatibility". If you ignore this warning and transform `samples` directly, the `output` will be modified too and that's not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a solution something like that. :) I definitely want to scale the 'output', as I am working on a car value predictor application and there are prices like 50.000.000HUF and even more than that. The error would be much higher if I don't scale the output, right? Currently I am doing the following scaling: 'input_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(samples_train['input'])' ... 'output_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(samples_train['output'])' ... And after the prediction I use the inverse scaler to transform back. Should I change this?

Comment: The absolute value of an error doesn't play a role. The problem with `X` scaling (lack of scaling to be exact) is that it makes certain algorithms and methods work poorly (SVM, KNN, NN). So it is a necessary step. Just to be clear: there's nothing wrong with extra scaling of `y`, but it doesn't add a lot of value. That is the reason why `StandardScaler` ignores it.